# Show .gif from Firebase Storage link

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

I have link in my Firebase Storage on .gif file

```
String gifUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rokitskiydev-a18ca.appspot.com/o/WF%2F10-16-02-Digital-15.gif?alt=media&token=0354f6e6-4292-4911-9302-49281d293a80";
```

I try use Picasso and Glide. But I can show only image of this gif.

```
GlideApp.with(context).load(gifUrl).into(ImageView);
```

If i get another link, an example `http://i.imgur.com/1ALnB2s.gif` it's OK!

How can I do this?

Comment: Do not paste the entire URL from firebase, just get the downloadurl from the getDownloadUrl method from datasnapshot ( if you have your image stored in the database)

Comment: @GastónSaillén this link return getDownloadUrl()    (downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();)

Comment: if you go to the firebase storage and find the file, it haves another url ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén no

Answer (score 0):

Get the **downloadUrl** of the gif and then use that to load the gif with Glide.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(imageView);
Glide.with(this).load(downloadUrl).into(imageViewTarget);
```

For newer versions of Glide try this:

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(imageUrl)
.asGif()
.placeholder(R.drawable.loading2)
.crossFade()
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: I use 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'. I don't have GlideDrawableImageViewTarget

Comment: Edited ans. You may try now

Comment: the problem is not glide, the problem is just the url as OP says

Comment: @GastónSaillén but i see first frame this gif. It is not animated.

Answer (score 0):

As Glide Documentation says,

You can use `.asGif()` to force the library to load an animated gif and fail if it is not :

```
Glide.with(activity).load(gifUrl).asGif().into(view);
```

try this

Check the doc: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-displaying-gifs-and-videos

also as FirebaseDoc says you can do this to load an image/gif with glide

first declare this in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // FirebaseUI Storage only
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
}
```

then

this to load your image with firebase

```
// Reference to an image file in Firebase Storage
StorageReference storageReference = ...;

// ImageView in your Activity
ImageView imageView = ...;

// Load the image using Glide
Glide.with(this /* context */)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(storageReference)
        .into(imageView);
```

if you need the url of your image/gif file, you can do this

```
storageRef.child("your/firebase/imagepath.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
            Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
            generatedFilePath = downloadUri.toString(); /// The string(file link) that you need
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });
```

Comment: Glide.with(context).load(watchFace.getImageUrl())
                .asGif() // Cannot resolved
                .into(vh.faceImageView);

Comment: read what asGif do, it checks if you are trying to load a gif or a image

Comment: also if your other link works, it might be due the firebase link

Comment: after .load add this .apply(new RequestOptions() .placeHolder())

Comment: also , check that you have at least this compile tu use asGif() 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

Comment: but ifyou are using older version of glide like 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1' , just place asGif() before .load , but if you are working with 4.1.1 and above asGif() is not required, it will load automatically

Comment: i try with 3.7.0 its not work. Because i think use new version

Comment: did you followed the official firebase docs ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url

Comment: check that firebase uses this with glide using(new FirebaseImageLoader())